# Advanced jQuery .animation problem -- animates from wrong side

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm working on creating a jQuery book online that utilizes .animate to create nifty effects. I'm nearly finished with the initial animation and design, but have run across a pretty irritating snag.

Have a look at http://notebook.dauidusdesign.com to see the problem.

The trouble:
When you click on the right arrow or hover to see the next page, all works exactly right. But, when you hover on the left arrow, the animation occurs on the wrong side of the page... it should occur on the left side and show the page behind it. I'm pretty sure it comes down to something in the code below, as that is where the majority of hover animations occur.

For a look at the rest of the code, visit the site above, view the source and check out the file jquery.booklet.1.1.0.js. The code below begins at line 401.

Thanks for the help!

```
//add page hover animations
if(opts.hovers){
    ctrlsN.hover(
        function(){
            if(!busy && opts.curr+2 <= opts.pTotal-2){
                //animate
  p2.stop().animate({right:5, 'width':opts.pWidth-140, 'height':opts.pHeight}, 800, opts.easing);
  p2wrap.stop().animate({left:"-5px"}, 800, opts.easing);
  p3.stop().animate({'left':opts.width-180, 'width':30, paddingLeft: 50}, 800, opts.easing);
  p3wrap.stop().animate({left:10}, 800, opts.easing);
  rhover = true;
            }
        },
        function(){
            if(!busy && opts.curr+2 <= opts.pTotal-2){
  p2.stop().animate({right:0, 'width':opts.pWidth, 'height':opts.pHeight}, 800, opts.easing);
  p2wrap.stop().animate({left:0}, 800, opts.easing);
  p3.stop().animate({'left':opts.width, 'width':0, paddingLeft: 0}, 800, opts.easing);
  p3wrap.stop().animate({left:0}, 800, opts.easing);                
  rhover = false;
            }
        }
    );
    ctrlsP.hover(
        function(){
            if(!busy && opts.curr-2 >= 0){
                //animate
  p1.stop().animate({left:5, 'width':opts.pWidth-140}, 800, opts.easing);
  p1wrap.stop().animate({right:"-5px", 'right':opts.pWidthH-140}, 800, opts.easing);
  p0.stop().animate({'right':opts.width-180, left:100, 'width':80}, 800, opts.easing);
  p0wrap.stop().animate({right:10}, 800, opts.easing);
  lhover = true;
            }
        },
        function(){
            if(!busy && opts.curr-2 >= 0){
  p1.stop().animate({left:0, 'width':opts.pWidth}, 800, opts.easing);
  p1wrap.stop().animate({right:0, 'right':opts.pWidthH}, 800, opts.easing);
  p0.stop().animate({'right':opts.width-0, left:0, 'width':0}, 800, opts.easing);
  p0wrap.stop().animate({right:0}, 800, opts.easing);
  lhover = false;
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: This doesn't help you - but awesome effects. Well done (so far)!

Comment: You need some consistency in your code, Dave. Half your animate functions have quoted params, half don't.

Comment: AlienWebguy,     Yeah, that's how I've been keeping track of which functions I want to keep as is and which ones may need some tweaking later on.  Rest assured, I'll give them all the same formatting once the project is finished.

Comment: It's really hard to figure out exactly what's wrong with the code because we have no idea what p0, p1, and p2 are.  The only thing I can say is that there's an animation that shrinks the current page that you want to flip, and that animation is happening in the same fashion for both left and right pages.  Once you fix that, it will work.  Fiddling with your app make me dizzy after a few minutes :<

Comment: @vinceh -- I thought of that being the cause of this problem.  I'll just have to look through the code again to find where the animation is defined.  I took this code from an open-source project (http://builtbywill.com/code/booklet/) and implemented it to work for my usage.  Looks like I'll be adding some more changes to the source code.  Thanks for verifying my suspicions!